# How to use regex to reverse text in bash script?

Tags: regex, bash

e.g.

```
ip_a="172.31.50.48"
```

reversing as

```
ip_r="48.50.31.172" << use regex on this line for evaluate text then assign to ip_r
```

or domain

```
domain_a="www.linux.org"
```

reversing as

```
domain_r="org.linux.www" << use regex on this line for evaluate text then assign to domain_r
```

Comment: no regex required if python is used, `'.'.join(reversed(name.split('.'))`

Comment: no regex required if perl is used, `join '.', reverse split '.', $str`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
ip_a="172.31.50.48"
ip_r=`echo $ip_a | awk '{n=split($0,A,".");S=A[n];{for(i=n-1;i>0;i--)S=S"."A[i]}}END{print S}'`
domain_a="www.linux.org"
domain_r=`echo $domain_a | awk '{n=split($0,A,".");S=A[n];{for(i=n-1;i>0;i--)S=S"."A[i]}}END{print S}'`
echo $ip_r
echo $domain_r
```

**OUTPUT**

```
48.50.31.172
org.linux.www
```

Comment: rev doesn't actually work. It reverses character-by-character so the result of "rev" of 12.34.56.78 is 87.65.43.21

Comment: @Agrajag Thanks for pointing that out. I misunderstood the IP reversal to mean character-by-character.

Answer (score 5):

Pure Bash, as described by Agrajag:

```
IFS='.'
array=( $ip )
n=${#array[@]}
for (( i=0; i<$((n/2)); i+=1 )); do
    save=${array[i]} 
    array[i]=${array[n-i-1]}
    array[n-i-1]=$save
done

printf "%s\n" "${array[*]}"
```

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you:

```
ip_a="172.31.50.48"
domain_a="www.linux.org"
ip_r=$(sed 'G;:a;s/\([^.]*\)\.\(.*\n\)/\2.\1/;ta;s/\n//' <<<$ip_a)
domain_r=$(sed 'G;:a;s/\([^.]*\)\.\(.*\n\)/\2.\1/;ta;s/\n//' <<<$domain_a)
echo -e "$ip_r\n$domain_r"
48.50.31.172
org.linux.www
```

Comment: Like this: domain_r=$(sed 'G;:a;s/\([^.]*\)\.\(.*\n\)/\2.\1/;ta;s/\n//' <<<$domain_a). Do not understand anything, but its short and working! thanks

Answer (score 0):

The best way to do this is not with a regexp. Instead split the strings by . to get arrays, then print the arrays in reverse order. How you do this, depends on the implementation-language, an example in python was given you as a comment above.

Pseudocode is as follows:

```
split string by . to obtain array.
reverse array
print array-elements, joined by .
```

Answer (score 0):

Another `awk` solution:

```
 echo www.what.ever |\
 awk -F '.' '{ for (i=NF; i<=1 ; i--) { output=$i FS } ; print gensub(".$","","g",output) }'
```